# Similarity transformation that controls maximum and minimum value of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $M$ be a positive $(M_{ij}>0 \ \forall i,j)$ symmetric matrix.

I wonder if there exists a similarity transformation $D$ that can control its maximum entry and minimum entry in a certain range or ratio?
I.e.
$$
    A=D^{-1}MD\\
    \frac{A_{\max}}{A_{\min}} < K, \quad K>0
$$

This problem comes from an algorithm I am currently working on, which is to solve for the eigenpair of $M$.

But the algorithm shows numerical instability when the above quotient is large. So I wonder if there is a similarity transformation that can control the quotient.

A transformation that can preserve the tridiagonal property is even better.

Thank you.

Comment: You can transform your matrix $M$ into a diagonal matrix with positive entries. But the quotient can become arbitrary large. I don't understand your intention.

Comment: Actually I am working on an algorithm to solve for eigenvalue and $M$ is actually tridiagonal. And I noticed that a large quotient will cause numerical instability in that algorithm. So I wonder if there is a similarity transform that can address this problem.

Comment: The last comment clarifies the question a lot, perhaps add it to the 'main' body of the question?

Comment: Added, thanks, Vincent.